# Problem with a Tkinter Menu in Python

Tags: menu, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm actually working on an image editor in Python with Tkinter (I know Python's not the best for image editing but that's for school, I didn't chose) and what I'm trying to do is saving every opened files in another file to add shortcut to the last five ones in the File menu.
The problem is that there's no problem at the start but when I open a new image it can't reconfigure the old shortcuts.
The error seems to indicate that it tries to configure a separator instead of a command. After playing with some print()s it seems that Tkinter see the first five entry then jump the next three and then see all the other. 
It's kinda messin' with my head.

Here's the code :

```
    f=open('.recentlyUsed', 'r+')
    f.readline() #Skipping the empty first line.
    recents=f.read().split('\n')
    c=0
    recents2=[] 
    for i in recents:    #Deleting the doubles.
        if i not in recents2:
            recents2+=[i]
    recents=recents2[:]
    c=0
    while fichier.index(c)==c: #Getting the number of files already displayed in
        c+=1                        #the menu.
        print(fichier.entryconfigure(c)) #Test : Printing the entry to know which 
    c-=7                                      #Tkinter sees or not.
    if c>=0:
        fichier.insert_separator(5)      #Doesn't insert a separator if there's no file displayed.
    if len(recents)>=1:  #If there's already a file displayed, juste modifying the label (the command doesn't need to.)
        if c>=1:
            fichier.entryconfigure(7, label=srecents[-1])
        else:
            fichier.insert_command(6, command=lambda: openRecent(-1), label=recents[-1])
        if len(recents)>=2:
            if c>=2:
                fichier.entryconfig(8, label=recents[-2])
            else:
                fichier.insert_command(6, command=lambda: openRecent(-2), label=recents[-2])
            if len(recents)>=3:
                if c>=3:
                    fichier.entryconfig(9, label=.recents[-3])
                else:
                    fichier.insert_command(6, command=lambda: openRecent(-3), label=recents[-3])
                if len(recents)>=4:
                    if c>=4:
                        fichier.entryconfig(10, label=recents[-4])
                    else:
                        fichier.insert_command(6, command=lambda: openRecent(-4), label=recents[-4])
                    if len(recents)>=5:
                        if c>=5:
                            fichier.entryconfig(11, label=recents[-5])
                        else:
                            fichier.insert_command(6, command=lambda: openRecent(-5), label=recents[-5])
    f.close()
```

And this code returns the following :

```
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Nouveau'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3071116428nouveau'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Ouvrir...'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056134764open'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Sauver'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'disabled'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056134892save'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Sauver sous...'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'disabled'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056134700saveAs'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'background': ('background', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Quitter'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056074828destroy'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Quitter'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056074828destroy'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}

#Now I try oening a new image (whether by clicking on one of the shortcut to a recent picture or by the open function a defined in the project).

{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Nouveau'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3071116428nouveau'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Ouvrir...'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', <bytecode object at 0x9870a68>), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Sauver'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'disabled'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056134892save'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Sauver sous...'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'disabled'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056134700saveAs'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', '/home/aquaj/workspace/projet1/lenna.pgm'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '160341260<lambda>'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', '/home/aquaj/workspace/projet1/boats.pgm'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '160341292<lambda>'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', '/home/aquaj/Projet_Programmation_1/Images/lena2.pgm'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056177964<lambda>'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'background': ('background', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Quitter'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056074828destroy'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Quitter'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056074828destroy'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1402, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/aquaj/workspace/projet1/main.py", line 244, in open
     self.recentUse(add=1)
  File "/home/aquaj/workspace/projet1/main.py", line 307, in recentUse
     self.fichier.entryconfig(9, label=self.recents[-3])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2669, in entryconfigure
     return self._configure(('entryconfigure', index), cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1187, in _configure
     self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-label"
```

Where it should display :

```
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Nouveau'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3071116428nouveau'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Ouvrir...'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', <bytecode object at 0x9870a68>), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Sauver'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'disabled'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056134892save'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Sauver sous...'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'disabled'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056134700saveAs'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'background': ('background', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', '/home/aquaj/workspace/projet1/feuille.pgm'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056177964<lambda>'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', '/home/aquaj/workspace/projet1/bateaux.pgm'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056177964<lambda>'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', '/home/aquaj/workspace/projet1/lenna.pgm'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '160341260<lambda>'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', '/home/aquaj/workspace/projet1/boats.pgm'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '160341292<lambda>'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', '/home/aquaj/Projet_Programmation_1/Images/lena2.pgm'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056177964<lambda>'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'background': ('background', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Quitter'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056074828destroy'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
{'foreground': ('foreground', '', '', '', ''), 'accelerator': ('accelerator', '', '', '', ''), 'hidemargin': ('hidemargin', '', '', 0, 0), 'label': ('label', '', '', '', 'Quitter'), 'underline': ('underline', '', '', -1, -1), 'bitmap': ('bitmap', '', '', '', ''), 'columnbreak': ('columnbreak', '', '', 0, 0), 'state': ('state', '', '', <index object at 0x968c230>, 'normal'), 'command': ('command', '', '', '', '3056074828destroy'), 'background': ('background', '', '', '', ''), 'compound': ('compound', 'compound', 'Compound', <index object at 0x9689428>, 'none'), 'font': ('font', '', '', '', ''), 'image': ('image', '', '', '', ''), 'activeforeground': ('activeforeground', '', '', '', ''), 'activebackground': ('activebackground', '', '', '', '')}
```

So if there's anyone who can see where's the problem comes from... ?

Answer (score 1):

The least complicated solution is to just recreate the whole menu from scratch rather than try to update certain items. It's quick, easy, and almost foolproof.

If you make the design decision to make the recent items the last items on the menu, you can delete just the recent files and append a fresh set. This is very easy since you know the index where the recent files begin unless you have a menu that grows and shrinks for other reasons.

So, don't try to update items in place, just delete and recreate.

Answer (score 0):

That long chain of `if`'s is definitely the wrong way of doing it.
I suggest you first remove all the old recent entries, and add the new ones instead.